# touchmove not fired in Chrome DevTool mobile emulator

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When using desktop Chrome DevTool's mobile emulator, I'm observing a strange behavior where the `touchmove` event is not fired if the center of the circular cursor in not over the target element.

Steps to reproduce using demo code below:.

1. Using the mobile emulator, hold down the cursor anywhere on the dark gray square and move the cursor around. The square turns red then green.
2. Repeat that, but position the cursor such that it is outside the square but slightly overlapping at the edge. The square turns red and stays red.

Is this a bug with the emulator? Could this happen on a real device?

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>
function onMove(e) {
  console.log('move');
  document.getElementById('x').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
function onEnd() {
  console.log('end');
  document.getElementById('x').style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
}
function onStart(e) {
  console.log('start');
  document.getElementById('x').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  e.target.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onMove, {passive: false});
  e.target.addEventListener('touchend', this.onEnd);
}
</script>

<div style="background: lightgray; width: 300px; height: 1000px">
<div id="x" style="background: gray; width: 200px; height: 200px;" onmousedown="" ontouchstart="onStart(event)"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed in testing (Chrome on Mac) is that clicking with the center of the circle cursor not over the target div doesn't work the first time. No events are fired. Then after you do it once, suddenly any part of the circle being over the div is sufficient to fire `onStart` and `onEnd`. So is touchmove not firing when it should, or are `onStart` and `onEnd` firing when they shouldn't? I think I would try hooking an actual phone up to your computer in mobile debug mode to see what actually happens on the phone.

Comment: I've noticed that as well (on Windows). Testing on a real Android device where it works fine, it seems like it is `touchmove` that doesn't fire, and it should work even the first time.